# pass id value to ionic modal on click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using a click event to open a modal window like this ,

But on this click event i need to pass an id value so that i can dispaly the details wit respect to that id value .this is the controller part ,

```
           $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function($ionicModal) {
                $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
            }, {
                // Use our scope for the scope of the modal to keep it simple
                scope: $scope,
                // The animation we want to use for the modal entrance
                animation: 'slide-in-up'
            });
```

is there any way to do this...???

Thanks.

Comment: You are passing in the current scope, so you can just put your id variable on the `$scope` object

Comment: I will get the id value from ng-repeat so how can i pass it to the controller

Comment: you probably click a button, so you can just do `ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="openModal(item.id)"`

Comment: and how will i get value in controller..???sorry i am new i ionic ....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You assign the current scope to your modal, so you can just assign the variable to the `$scope` object:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function($ionicModal) {
    $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
}, {
    // Use our scope for the scope of the modal to keep it simple
    scope: $scope,
    // The animation we want to use for the modal entrance
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
});

$scope.openModal = function(id) {
    $scope.selectedId = id;
    $scope.modal.show();
}
```

And in your view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"
        ng-click="openModal(item.id)">
        {{ item.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you have access to the id in your modal:

```
<div class="modal">
    <h1>{{ selectedId }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works I must say I'm disappointed there is no way to resolve a value to the modal without attaching it to the scope. Feels dirty.

Comment: @Franci you can always just create a new scope: `var scope = $scope.$new(true);`, which creates a new isolated scope

Comment: That's true, and it does address my concern but it's still unnecessary since you really should be able to pass references to the modal without having to rely on $scope. Even better would be if it was modeled after how bootstrap modal does it where you can resolve functions and return promises for async data required by the modal.

Answer (score 1):

If one needs to show up HTML content in model from scope. You will need to use

```
$scope.openModal = function(item) {
  $scope.modal=$ionicModal.fromTemplate('<ion-modal-view><b>'+item.id+'</b> 
  </ion-modal-view>',
  { animation: 'slide-in-up'});
  $scope.modal.open();
}
```